# My jupyter notebook keeps restarting when I try to run code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment

I have been successfully running code in a jupyter notebook and suddenly it wont run anything. On the bottom left when I hit execute it says Python3 busy and then restarting. I think it has to do with the fact that I shutdown and restarted Anaconda.

I tried switching environments but either I am not doing it correctly or that is not the issue

thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? That might clear up any issues with restarting Anaconda.

Comment: Dash thank you for your response. Yes I restarted my computer and Anaconda and this happened.